# Is it possible to flip columns of a table horizontally in Libreoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice

Exchanging the position of each column with another one:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should copy your table and put it into a LibreOffice Calc document.

Then switch, modify and change the cells.

At the end you need to re-transfer your table into the LibreOffice Writer document: select the table, copy it, and use paste special (`Ctrl+Shift+V`) to put it in the Writer document, according to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40126/how-to-copy-paste-a-table-from-libreoffice-calc-to-libreoffice-writer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your exact needs - your question isn't very precise...

To mirror a calc sheet horizontally, only affecting the **display**: enable CTL (complex text layout): Tools -> Options -> Language settings -> Languages -> Default languages for documents -> (enable). Now, the context menu of the sheet tab has an entry "Sheet Right-to-Left". This will arrange the complete sheet right-to-left, so the rightmost column is A, left of it is B and so on (found the solution [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/42602/is-there-any-option-to-flip-horizontally-a-sheet-in-calc/) - written by Lupp on ask.libreoffice.org)

To mirror the **content**: you can't do this using LO Calc. Calc allows only for **transposing**, e.g. to re-arrange an array so that columns are now rows and vice versa (in your example:

```
 A | B | C | D
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

would be transformed to

```
 A | 1
 B | 2
 C | 3
 D | 4
```

To **workaround**: use Gnumeric. Gnumeric has a "Paste Special" option "mirror horizontally". Just paste the content from Calc to Gnumeric, mirror and copy back to Calc.